# Client side validation for rails 3.1.X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-plugins

The normal client_side_validation gem does not work with rails 3.1 so i would like to ask if anybody knows any gem that works like the client_side_validation gem in rails 3.1 and can be compatible with devise. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at this:

https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations#readme

http://bcardarella.com/post/4211204716/client-side-validations-3-0

The project above seems to support 3.1.x. Are you not talking about this [gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/client_side_validations)?